# Can tkinter work with tox (on windows)?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, virtualenv, tox

I know that tkinter has issues working with virtual envs due to the binaries not being copied and that there are workarounds if I'm just using virtual envs, but what about the autogenerated virtual envs generated by tox? Is there any way to use something like tkinter with tox?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet but hopefully soon someone will address this problem and create a compatible virtual env.